# Error with Linux that doesn't happen with Windows

Tags: windows, linux

Recently I changed from Windows (Miktex) to Linux (TeX Live), thanks to my thesis, and now I need to keep making it work.

I now get a syntax error even though I didn't change anything from the last time I ran the script.

```
%% CHECK IF USING LUALATEX OR XELATEX

\newif\ifxetexorluatex
\begingroup\catcode94=7 \catcode0=9% --------erro in this line
\def\empty{}\def\next{^^^^0000}\expandafter\endgroup
\ifx\next\empty\xetexorluatextrue\else\xetexorluatexfalse\fi
\newcommand*{\ifxeorlua}[2]{\ifxetexorluatex#1\else#2\fi}
```

error message :

```
! Text line contains an invalid character.
l.90 \def\empty{}\def\next{^^^^0000}\expandafter\endgroup
A funny symbol that I can't read has just been input.
```

Comment: the code posted does not give an error with pdflatex, lualatex or xelatex but it doesn't do anything other than make some definitions. What error did you get (please show the exact error you get from the code posted) (you should mark code with an indent of 4 spaces or begen and end with three `\`\`\`` to mark a code block

Comment: you can use `\usepackage{iftex}` then `\iftutex` is true for xetex and luatex

Comment: I assume the blank lines were not intended and just due to markdown errors, as otherwise the `\expandafter` was not doing anything so I deleted them from the example.

Comment: Rather than reinvent the wheel, so to say, I would load the `iftex` package and use its `\iftutex` conditional to test whether either XeTeX or LuaTeX is in use.